# Lower bound on integral of coefficient in an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $\phi$ solves $x'' + A \left( t \right) x = 0$, is positive on $\left(0, b \right)$, and $\phi \left( 0 \right) = \phi \left( b \right) = 0$. ($A(t)$ is continuous) Is it true that
$$\int_{0}^{b} \left| A \left( t \right) \right| dt > \frac{4}{b}$$
Any help or hints appreciated.

One attempt: By the MVT for integrals, for some $0 < c < b$,

$$\int_0^b \left| A \left( t \right) \right| dt = b \left| A \left( c \right) \right| \geq b \inf_{0 \leq t \leq c} \left| A \left( t \right) \right| $$
However, I think this is too restrictive.

Another attempt: since $\int_0^b \left| A \left( t \right) \right| \phi \left( t \right) dt \leq M \int_0^b \left| A \left( t \right) \right| dt$, where $M = \sup \left| \phi \left( t \right) \right|$,
$$\int_0^b \left| A \left( t \right) \right| dt \geq \frac{1}{M} \int_0^b \left| A \left( t \right) \right| \phi \left( t \right) dt = \frac{1}{M} \int_0^b \left| A \left( t \right) \phi \left( t \right) \right| dt = \frac{1}{M} \int_0^b \left| \phi'' \left( t \right) \right| dt \geq \frac{1}{M} \left| \int_0^b \phi'' \left( t \right) dt \right| = \frac{1}{M} \left| \phi' \left( b \right) - \phi' \left( 0 \right) \right| $$
or, again by the MVT for integrals,
$$ = \frac{b}{M} \left| \phi'' \left( c \right) \right| $$
for some $0 < c < t$. Again, I'm not sure how to turn this into a solution.

FINAL EDIT: To anyone finding this result in the future, this is a famous result by Lyapunov. One may complete my second attempt as follows: Apply Rolle's theorem to obtain $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $s$ and $t$ such that $x'(t) = -M / \alpha$ and $x' (s) = M / \beta$, and $\beta + \alpha = b$. An application of the AGM inequality finishes the job.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I saw it mentioned offhand so I believe it's true, but I have no idea how to attack a proof for it.

Comment: Really nice name I suppose you are a biggest fan of Rheta 's Ziemann function...

Comment: Doesn't look right. Consider $A$ being a _very_ small constant.

Comment: I had made the question too specific. I have changed the upper bound to $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

You might be able to get the result by playing around with energy inequalities. 
 For example, if you multiply the equation by $\phi^{2p+1}$ (I'm using arbitrary $p$ to illustrate that you can multiply by any monotone $f(\phi)$ more generally), for any $p\ge 0$, and integrate from $0$ to $b$, you get
$$
\int_0^b\phi(x)^{2p+1}\phi''(x)dx+\int_0^bA(t)\phi(x)^{2p+2}dx=0.
$$ 
If you integrate by parts and apply $\phi(0)=\phi(b)=0$, you get the identity
$$
\int_0^bA(t)\phi(x)^{2p+2}dx=(2p+1)\int_0^b\phi(x)^{2p}\phi'(x)^2dx.
$$
The integrand on the right hand side is $[\phi(x)^p\phi'(x)]^2=\frac{1}{(p+1)^2}\psi'(x)^2$, where $\psi(x)=\phi(x)^{p+1}$.  By [Wirtinger's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger's_inequality_for_functions#Second_version), you get
$$
\int_0^1A(t)\phi(x)^{2p+2}dx\ge \frac{\pi^2(2p+1)}{b^2(p+1)^2}\int_0^1 \phi(x)^{2p+2}dx.
$$
This seems to imply
$$
\max_{[0,b]}A(t)\ge \frac{\pi^2(2p+1)}{b^2(p+1)^2}.
$$
So taking $p=0$, we see that $\max A\ge 2\pi^2/b^2$.

Comment: Thank you for this. Wirtinger's Inequality in particular seems like it may be helpful.